# Setting the output folder and file url separately; Webpack file-loader with Django

Tags: javascript, django, url, webpack

I'm using Webpack to create several bundles that are loaded within their respective Django applications. All the front-end (static) assets are stored in a separate folder outside of the Django framework, and each bundle gets dropped into the appropriate static subfolder when Webpack is run.

The problem I'm having is when bundling images using the file-loader. The export location for these images should be `/common/static/[file]`, but when the url strings are replaced in the stylesheets, they need to point at `/static/[file]`. Since Django doesn't expose `/common/` as part of the path, the img urls end up pointing to a non-existent location ( `http://host/common/static/...` instead of `http://host/static/...`).

I thought I had found the answer I needed with the "context" value provided by the file-loader ([LINK](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/395)) but I'm either understanding the purpose of "context" incorrectly, or using it incorrectly.

Here's some of my config file. I've trimmed some of the irrelevant bits such as `plugins`, `externals` and `resolve`.

```js
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        './agent/static/agent_bundle': './ui/agent/entry.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js(x)?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        },{
            test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&name=common/static/[name]-[hash].[ext]&context=static',
        },{
            test: /\.less$/,
            loader: 'style!css?sourceMap!less?sourceMap'
        },{
            test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff&name=common/static/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
        },{
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=common/static/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
        }]
    }
};
```

I'm actually processing images via url-loader, but files that are over the 8k limit are handed off to the file-loader (from what I've read).

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `output.publicPath` option. I think the example at https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue right now. Seems that `file-loader` outputs files in different locations, depending on whether you're using `webpack-dev-server` or `webpack` when compiling.